# angularjs textbox enter does not execute appropriate keyup event

Tags: angularjs, keyup

Inside a div I have a textbox and 2 buttons, I have added check with ng-keyup that should execute a method once enter key is pressed.

But only the first button's click event gets executed.

```
<div class="SearchBox">
   <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.searchBoxText" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 ? ctrl.searchButtonClicked(text) : null; $event.keyCode == 27 ? ctrl.clearSearchBoxText() : null;"/>
   <button ng-click="ctrl.clearButtonClicked()" ><span class="icon-close"></span></button>
   <button ng-click="ctrl.searchButtonClicked()"><span class="icon-search2"></span></button>
</div>
```

So by looking in code it seems if Enter is pressed (KeyCode = 13) , method named '*searchButtonClicked*' will gets executed, but actually method '*clearButtonClicked*' gets executed.

But after '*clearButtonClicked*' gets executed '*searchButtonClicked*' method gets executed.

I have no idea why on enter key press method '*clearButtonClicked*' gets executed first.

Any idea ?

Comment: I've checked your code and it works just fine: http://codepen.io/maurycyg/pen/YwEXPe?editors=101

Comment: @maurycy, yes it is in codepen. but not sure why not in my application.

Comment: that means that code you presented is working as expected and the fault is somewhere else, you have maybe other event listener that prevents the correct behaviour?

Comment: Yes, I get that , but still not able to find what actually causing that.
Once i tried to put 'Search' div first and then 'Clear' div, then it works fine.
So , anyhow first div's click event handler gets executed